# How to update CVV of stored credit card on braintree

Tags: php, credit-card, braintree

I am using braintree Payments on magento store. I have a featured to stored maskedNumber of used credit card.I am storing related token number of valuted CC. Now I want to give option to change/update Cvv of stored credit card.

I need your help here that how can I do this ? Which call I need to execute for update cvv of stored cc.

Comment: Delete old. Store new card.

Comment: @Dagon any other method ?

Comment: if the cvv changes its a new card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/)</sub>

> [The CVV will never be stored in the gateway](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/ruby#cvv).

We do not store the cvv, it is only used for verification purposes. If you wish to re-verify a payment method, you can provide a form via hosted fields to post only the cvv and then run a PaymentMethod update with [verify_card](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/ruby#options.verify_card) set to true and the nonce generated from hosted fields.